# Formula for expectation that works both for the continuous and discrete cases

Tags: expected-value, notation

Consider a random variable $X$ with support $\mathcal{X}$ and probability distribution $P$.  I want to write down the formula for the expectation of $X$ (other than $E(X)$) that generically works for both the continuous and discrete cases.

Is the following expression 
$$ 
\int_{ \mathcal{X}} x  P(\text{d}x) 
$$
generic enough?

My understanding is that the expression above definitively works for the continuous case. However, I'm not sure that when $\mathcal{X}$ is finite, the above expression becomes
$$
\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x P(x)
$$
Could you advise?

Comment: You seem to be more concerned about notation than the underlying theory; you might want to look up Lebesgue integration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) for the latter, and simply use the associated notation for the former.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Could you advise more specifically about my question?

Comment: I tend to use the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral notation $\int_a^b f(x)\,dg(x)$, as under "Definition" in the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue–Stieltjes_integration.

Comment: Note that this covers more than just discrete or continuous as well.