# Multi-dimensional Lebesgue integral applied to probability measures

Tags: probability, expected-value, notation, integral

I have a question on multi-dimensional Lebesgue integral when applied to probability measures.

In particular, consider the random variables $Y,X,\epsilon,T,V$, with supports $\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{X},\mathcal{E},\mathcal{T},\mathcal{V}$, respectively.

Small case letters denote realisations below.

$\mathcal{Y}$ is finite.

Suppose that also $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{T},\mathcal{V}$ are finite. Then, by the law of total probability,

$$
(*) \hspace{1cm}P(y|x)=\sum_{e\in \mathcal{E},t\in \mathcal{T},v\in \mathcal{V}} P(y|x,e,t) \times  P(e|x)\times P(t|x,e,v)\times P(v|e,x)
$$

I would like to rewrite ($*$) in a way that is general enough to include both the cases  $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{T},\mathcal{V}$ finite and $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{T},\mathcal{V}$ non-finite.

From reading the comments to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/formula-for-expectation-that-works-both-for-the-continuous-and-discrete-cases) question referred to the 1 dimensional case, I have inferred that the following expression may be the correct way to go, but I would like your confirmation: 
$$
P(y|x)= \int_{\mathcal{E}\times \mathcal{T}\times \mathcal{V}} P(y|x,e,t) \times  \text{d} (P(e|x)\times P(t|x,e,v)\times P(v|e,x))
$$

Comment: Once again, you seem to be focusing more on notation than on the underlying theory.  To address your question, however, $\int_{\mathcal{E}\times \mathcal{T}\times \mathcal{V}} P(y|x,e,t)\text{d}P(e,t,v|x)$ would seem to me to work.

Comment: Thanks, but for reasons too long to explain I need to use an expression with the three probabilities separated, rather than with the joint. Thanks.